# Android app freezes when calling viewPager.setAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

My app stops responding when I call `mViewPager.setAdapter`. As soon as this happens the `LOGCAT` outputs the follwoing message plenty times:

> "Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 253980(5MB)
>   AllocSpace objects, 16(256KB) LOS objects, 8% free, 44MB/48MB, paused
>   5.693ms total 37.544ms"

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_options, container, false);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_options);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        return inflatedView;
    }

    private class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private static final int TABS = 3;

        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0: return new OptionsFragment();
                default: return new OptionsFragment();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TABS;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a total disaster. Recursive call to same fragment /

Comment: That's because I haven't done the new View jet

Comment: Whats this mean ?

Comment: It's the first time I work with ViewPager and to try if it works correctly I returned a new OptionsFragment in getItem() because I haven't done the View what should be displayed there jet

Comment: Ok good luck with your experiments .

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0: return new OptionsFragment();
                default: return new OptionsFragment();
            }
        }
```

Why OptionsFragment contain OptionsFragment. It's loop view

Comment: I haven't done the new View jet and to try out if it works I returned a new OptionsFragment

Comment: Please replace OptionsFragment to new Fragment

Comment: Thank you, after I have finished the new Fragment and returned it, it worked correctly